# How can I create a variable-width stroke in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

Is there any way to create a variable-width stroke on a drawn path? I need to imitate a pen pressure effect (without using a tablet). Can I do this by changing some properties of a stoke?
Thanks in advance

Comment: look into [graphics.lineStyle()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stroke that has different width throughout its length in AS3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15322198/stroke-that-has-different-width-throughout-its-length-in-as3)

Comment: this was asked first!

Answer (score 2):

usually dont like just posting links! But this is what you need
 [A Smooth and Responsive Drawing Application in AS3](http://www.flashandmath.com/advanced/smoothdraw/index.html)
It determines the thickness by the mouse speed, you can obviously change that to fit your needs