# Stroke that has different width throughout its length in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I need a stroke that has a different width on different places throughout its length. For example, I have a path that I've drawn manually (without using AS3) and I want to assign it a stroke that has 0 width at the beginning and at the end of the path's length, and 10 width in the middle of the path's length so that the stroke's width can change gradually throughout the length of the path.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The solution is to use the graphics class to create some kind of "triangle" with the shape of the curve. But it's quite beyond the scope of a SO answer... First you need to study bezier curves, and then imagine how you would do it in a vector software by hand. That way you'll be able to make an algorithm to do it dynamically by code.

Comment: possibly same question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315724/how-can-i-create-a-variable-width-stroke-in-as3

Answer (score 2):

In as3 you'd use [lineStyle()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#lineStyle%28%29):

```
var segs:int = 32;//number of segments/'circle resolution'
var ai:Number = (Math.PI * 2) / segs;//angle increment
var offx:int = stage.stageWidth/2;//circle centre x
var offy:int = stage.stageHeight/2;//circle centre y
var rad:Number = 100;//circle radius
var maxWidth:Number = 18;

for(var i:int = 0 ; i < segs; i++){
    var a:Number = ai * i;
    var cx:Number = offx + Math.cos(a) * rad;
    var cy:Number = offy + Math.sin(a) * rad;
    graphics.lineStyle(i/segs * maxWidth);
    if(i == 0) graphics.moveTo(cx,cy);
    graphics.lineTo(cx,cy);
}
```

[image: AS3 line style]

but you mentioned you need that drawn in the Flash editor, therefore you need to script it.
You can script the Flash editor using [JSFL](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/extend/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9024f3f-7ffa.html).

Here's a JSFL port of the above:

```
var doc = fl.getDocumentDOM();
var segs = 32;//number of segments/'circle resolution'
var ai = (Math.PI * 2) / segs;//angle increment
var offx = doc.width/2;//circle centre x
var offy = doc.height/2;//circle centre y
var rad = 100;//circle radius
var maxWidth = 10;

for(var i = 0 ; i < segs; i++){
    var a = ai * i;
    var an = ai * (i+1);//next angle
    var cx = offx + Math.cos(a) * rad;//current pt
    var cy = offy + Math.sin(a) * rad;
    var nx = offx + Math.cos(an) * rad;//next pt
    var ny = offy + Math.sin(an) * rad;
    //this is mainly what you're after
    var s = doc.getCustomStroke("toolbar");
    s.thickness= (i/segs)*maxWidth;
    doc.setCustomStroke(s);

    doc.addNewLine({x:cx,y:cy},{x:nx,y:ny});
}
```

Create a new flash document, then a new Flash JavaScript File and run the above code:

[image: circle jsfl]

Stroke's [thickness](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/extend/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9024f3f-78bc.html) property is what you're after. 
You can also create your custom drawing tools with JSFL.
Check out [Extending Macromedia Flash MX 2004: Complete Guide and Reference to JavaScript Flash] (which sells pretty cheap now), it's the best thing you can get on the subject.
There's also a free chapter on creating [Tools](http://web.archive.org/web/20051212133929/http://www.friendsofed.com/books/1590593049/3049.pdf) which is exactly you need.

Another option might be to script Radomír Měch's [Deco Tool](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/deco_intro.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader_2) procedural engine. Unfortunately it's not well [documented](http://www.adobe.com/technology/projects/deco.html).

If you're getting into JSFL do checkout Dave Stewart's awesome [xJSFL](http://www.xjsfl.com)

Although you mentioned Flash, you might also want to look into the [Scriptographer](http://scriptographer.org/) free plugin for Illustrator which is also scriptable through JavaScript and Illustrator produces vector graphics you can easily import back in Flash.